# Using d3.js to display a gps route on OpenStreetMap?

Tags: gps, d3.js, openstreetmap

I'm thinking of using d3.js to display a gps route using OpenStreetMap as map.
I would like to be able to click anywhere along the route and get the corresponding location and timestamp. The gps locations can be anywhere around the world.

I'm new to the geo thing and not sure how to start or if this is a good approach.

/Lars

Comment: Sounds like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) would be a better place to start.

Comment: Or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) which can be even more beginner-friendly.

Comment: Thanks, will check those links